# Error when running Windows Mobile application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am writing a hello world program for Windows Mobile, just for the fun of it. (I am aware that it is a dead platform)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class HelloWorldForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        Label lblHello;
        Button btnClose;

        public HelloWorldForm()
        {
            this.Text = "Hello, world!";
            btnClose = new Button();
            lblHello = new Label();
            btnClose.Click += new EventHandler(btnClose_Click);
            btnClose.Text = "Close";
            btnClose.Location = new Point (10, 100);
            btnClose.Size = new Size(200, 50);
            lblHello.Text = "Hello, world! - From the Tectra team";
            lblHello.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            lblHello.Size = new Size(200, 50);
            SuspendLayout();
            this.Controls.Add(lblHello);
            this.Controls.Add(btnClose);
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            HelloWorldForm helloworld = new HelloWorldForm();
            Application.Run( helloworld );
        }
    }
}
```

I used the C# Compiler in SDK Command Prompt. When I run the exe it works fine in Windows 10. When I run it in the Windows Mobile emulator, however, I get this error:

```
File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089', or one of its dependencies, was not found.
```

Do I need a newer version of the .NET Compact Framework? Any help is welcome as I am quite perturbed about this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am aware this is a weird question. I just enjoy the idea of making a program for an obsolete platform for some reason.

Comment: How can you run a exe in windows mobile? Something is missing.

Comment: This is Windows Mobile, rather than Windows Phone?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make a program for old Windows Mobile PDAs.

Comment: The problem is that you need a SmartDevice aware compiler and the Compact Framework 2.0/3.5 runtimes (and compile against them). This is only possible with Visual Studio Pro 2008 and the Windows Mobile 6.x SDK.

Comment: @josef I found a way to make it work without VS 2008. I used the SDK Command Prompt. My app runs fine in the emulator. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work without VS 2008. I used the SDK Command Prompt. I found the command here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31861/Windows-Mobile-Development-Without-Visual-Studio. My app runs fine in the emulator. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is VS 2008 (no typo) and the Windows Mobile 6.x SDKs installed on your maschine.
Newer versions of Visual Studio do not support compact framework

Comment: I tried downloading VS 2008 Express. However, it turns out you need the pro version to make Windows Mobile apps.